# How to read response from a POST volley?

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

I'm really new on android and I'm wokring on a login system, I'm using volley to post the data....the problem thatm I'm having is when i try to read the response....
the response looks like this:

> {"st":"no","Message":"Error"}

I'm trying to access only st or message is there a way to do that ? I tried doing:

> response[i] ----Array type expexted found ' org.json.JSONObject'

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { 
                    Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + response.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Values: " + response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            });

            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
response.getString("Message")
```

to get a message from given JSON

Comment: Thanks for your response...when i use thtat i get the erorr " unhandled exception org.json.jsonexception" any ideas why

Comment: Catch that exception and paste the message please

Comment: Bro I feel so dumb, I wasn't using the try/catch block.....now is working fine....thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {
           JSONObject api_response = new JSONObject(response);
           String message = api_response.getString("Message")
       } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();           
       }
```

Its important to catch the json exception just in case the response string cannot be converted to json object. Then use the getString() to get the message from the created json object.